# Convert checkbox state to boolean value

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

So for a register form in a Laravel application I need a student to check a checkbox if they are an outgoing student. In the RegisterController.php the is_outgoing value is validated to be a boolean.

I am having difficulties returning the is_outgoing value with the form as a boolean true of false (based on if it is checked or not)

My best attempt is shown below, but the RegisterController doesn't seem te recieve any value for is_outgoing as the register form always trows "is outgoing field is required".

I tried renaming the actual checkbox under a different name, and adding a hidden input using the is_outgoing name using JQuery based on the checkbox state.

HTML:

```
<form id="#form" method="POST" 
      action="{{ route('register') }}" 
      onsubmit="checkboxToBoolean()">
```

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="is_outgoing_checkbox" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">
        {{ __('I am an outgoing student') }}
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input id="is_outgoing_checkbox" 
               type="checkbox" 
               class="form-control @error('is_outgoing') is-invalid @enderror" 
               name="is_outgoing_checkbox">
        @error('is_outgoing')
            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </span>
        @enderror
    </div>
</div>
```

Script at bottom of HTML:

```
<script>
function checkboxToBoolean() {
    let is_outgoing = $("#is_outgoing_checkbox").is(":checked");
    $("<input />")
        .attr("type", "hidden")
        .attr("name", "is_outgoing")
        .attr("value", is_outgoing)
        .appendTo("#form")
    ;
}
</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: When you call a function from onsubmit on your form, the form will either submit if the function returns true, or not submit if it returns false or something else. My guess is that your method in RegisterController isn't being called because checkToBoolean doesn't return true. The value for is_outgoing should show up in your controller if you look in the form values that get passed. You can dd() the values getting passed to see what you end up with when the form submits.

Comment: `RegisterController doesn't seem te recieve any value for is_outgoing as the register form always trows "is outgoing field is required"` - I am guessing but this sounds like you are doing validation in the controller, and that you have specified that the `is_outgoing` field is a *required* field, is that correct?

Comment: If so, it sounds like a checkbox is the wrong input type for this question.  When checked, a checkbox's value will be included in the form submission, but when not checked, the checkbox does not appear at all.  If you make that field required, it means the only option to pass validation is to always check the checkbox. This is more appropriate for eg a "I have read and accept the terms and conditions" option on a form.  If you require an a/b answer, either change your checkbox to 2 radios, or make the checkbox *not* required, and interpret no value as "not outgoing". You don't need any JS.